# Unable to place a div or button next to image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place the "View my Resume" div next to the linkedin image, but the div is getting placed little bit downwards. I've tried using float and inline-block but the div always remains a little downwards than the image.

*snapshot:*

[image: snapshot]

*html:*

```
<div id="DIV_1">

        <a href="" style="text-decoration:none;">
            <img src="linkedin.png" style="display: inline-block;">            
        </a>

        <div id="BUTTON_4" style="display: inline-block;">
            <span id="SPAN_5">View my Resume</span>
        </div>

</div>
```

*css:*

```
#DIV_1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(34, 34, 34);
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 572px;
    border: 0px none rgb(34, 34, 34);
    font: normal normal normal 13px/normal Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(34, 34, 34) none 0px;
}

#SPAN_5 {
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    cursor: default;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(68, 68, 68);
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
    align-self: flex-start;
    border: 0px none rgb(68, 68, 68);
    font: normal normal bold 12px/27px Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(68, 68, 68) none 0px;
}

#BUTTON_4 {
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    height: 29px;
    min-width: 54px;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(68, 68, 68);
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 114px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(245, 245, 245), rgb(241, 241, 241)) repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392);
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal bold 11px/29px Arial;
    margin: 16px 8px;
    outline: rgb(68, 68, 68) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 8px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tCrC3/

Comment: did you tried `align:left|right|middle|top|bottom` in `img's` `css`?

Comment: Do you have a link? I'm sure it'd be a lot easier to solve in 1 minute with Chrome Dev Tools... But on first look, I'd just add padding or margin, or use display:inline-block with line-height.

Comment: @VedantTerkar all align aren't working

Comment: @Ruslan padding or margin to img shifts the div even downwards

Comment: You have an accepted answer, but you could mark this up better :) Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/6345K/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) (with a value of `middle`) to the style of your `img`:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" style="vertical-align: middle;">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Av4hB/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should put that structure inslide UL and LI elements (Lists).

But talking about your specific problem, CSS aren't still efficient doing vertical aligment. So, your button its downwards because it haves some margin ("margin: 16px 8px;") so you need delete it or add it to the image too.

I hope it helps.